# Не работает IntelliSense для C# в VScode под GNU\Linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code, mono, intellisense

Расширение установлено, проект создан через dotnet 2.2.102. Monodevelop также установлен. Из логов OmniSharp понял, что он не может найти msbuilder. Нашёл, установил, но не помогло. Два дня пытаюсь найти решение, нагугленные решения не помогают, ни установка ранней версии плагина, ни переустановка VSC, ни установка MSBuilder.
Ошибки те же, IntelliSense не работает.
Вот логи от OmniSharp:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager:_queue' (9) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.24.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeTypeHandle.is_subclass_of(intptr,intptr)
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.IsSubclassOf (System.RuntimeType childType, System.RuntimeType baseType) [0x00016] in <f12ca6e34cfa434b9c747551ef070076>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.IsSubclassOf (System.Type type) [0x00020] in <f12ca6e34cfa434b9c747551ef070076>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.IsValueTypeImpl () [0x00026] in <f12ca6e34cfa434b9c747551ef070076>:0 
  at System.Type.get_IsValueType () [0x00000] in <f12ca6e34cfa434b9c747551ef070076>:0 
  at System.Type.get_IsClass () [0x0000b] in <f12ca6e34cfa434b9c747551ef070076>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector.InspectTypeForPart (System.Reflection.TypeInfo type, System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.DiscoveredPart& part) [0x0000b] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] types, System.Composition.Convention.AttributedModelProvider attributeContext) [0x00037] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer () [0x00042] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder.Build () [0x00191] in <c01404811b784b23ba2b531f165478f7>:0 
  at OmniSharp.Stdio.Host..ctor (System.IO.TextReader input, OmniSharp.Stdio.Services.ISharedTextWriter writer, OmniSharp.IOmniSharpEnvironment environment, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration configuration, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder compositionHostBuilder, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) [0x0007e] in <de2ffba991de4e9eafc3296817611843>:0 
  at OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__1 () [0x00116] in <93ea459c1f92407098a355199aa33d94>:0 
  at OmniSharp.CommandLineApplication+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<OnExecute>b__0 () [0x0000b] in <c01404811b784b23ba2b531f165478f7>:0 
  at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute (System.String[] args) [0x0035b] in <e56ebbc3ed87488b8e26736bbadaa5d3>:0 
  at OmniSharp.CommandLineApplication.Execute (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] args) [0x00042] in <c01404811b784b23ba2b531f165478f7>:0 
  at OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Main>b__0 () [0x00028] in <93ea459c1f92407098a355199aa33d94>:0 
  at OmniSharp.HostHelpers.Start (System.Func`1[TResult] action) [0x0001c] in <c01404811b784b23ba2b531f165478f7>:0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашёлся ответ. Мне подсказали, что в настройках VSC (File->Preferences->Settings) есть пункт Omnisharp Use Global Mono, нужно выставить значение "never", после чего перезапустить среду. Всё работает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем, но это натолкнуло меня на мысль и решение как я и думал лежало на поверхности, а точнее в настройках:)

Omnisharp: Enable Roslyn Analyzers
Enables support for roslyn analyzers, code fixes and rulesets.

Ставьте галочку, закройте и откройте VSC и будет вам с счастье, мне помогло!
VSC v. 1.76.3 - 2023 год